# Proper way to hold 3 chamber ocarina?

Tags: technique, ocarina

I've picked up the multi-chamber ocarina, after playing tenor recorder for years.

I have a 'regular' triple alto A ocarina.

My question is, what's the proper way to hold the thing so that I can switch between chambers smoothly?

I can't find much info online about technique for multi-chambered ocarinas. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I myself have never played a multi-chamber ocarina, but a while ago I wanted to buy one and did some research on the topic and on the miscellanea of playing it.

At that time, I remember finding [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bSJcLIvxPsQ) that seemed very informative of the basic technique of dealing with switches between chambers. Here he uses a double ocarina, but the idea is the same if you are playing a triple one.